# Looking to get millisecondes value from: microtime(true) and number_format()

Tags: php

Ok, I know this is not the first question about microtime and number_format but it seem there is no one able to come up with a dummy proof answer. So, as the dummy, here is my question:

How can I output my result from 2 microtime(true) variables in millisecondes. By that I mean 1 being 1 milliseconds and 1000 being 1 secondes.

So if it took less then a millisecondes, i get 1. If it took 1/2 of a second, I get 500.

I currently do this: 
number_format((microtime(true)-$timetrace), 4)

And I get this:
1,391,490,671.8339 
=)

$timetrace was set before in the code as $timetrace = microtime(true). Thansk for the help and if this was answer before in a one line command, I am truly sorry for asking that again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `number_format`.
My bet is, you did not put what you intended in your `$timetrace` variable.

See this example:

```
<?php
$timetrace = microtime(true);
sleep (1); // wait about 1 second
$elapsed_time = microtime(true) - $timetrace;
echo "$elapsed_time<br>";
echo number_format($elapsed_time, 4) . "<br>";
?>
```

output:

```
1.0120580196381
1.0121
```

Comment: Hey thanks! But when I use true, I get value with E at the end, even with a number format 4. Or I get value in the millions. Is there any config server that can affect such functions? Especially Number_format maybe?

Comment: Nope. You are passing a wrong value `number_format`, that's all. If your `$timetrace` variable is not set properly, the difference will be huge and you will get a silly output. As I already said, print the contents of `$timetrace` and you will see that it does not contain what you expect.

Comment: You put mu in the right direction big time. I ended up with a slightly different function to manage it, but thanks a tons!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Based on kuroi neko suggestion, I did built a little funciton and it work perfectly! Thank you a lot!!

```
Function ms($overall=0)
{
global $timetrace;
global $starttrace;

if ($overall==1){
    $result = microtime(true) - $initialtrace;
}else{
    $result = microtime(true) - $timetrace;
}

$result = number_format($result, 4);
$result = $result * 1000;
if ($result < 1)$result = 1;

// Reset timetrace
$timetrace = microtime(true);
return $result." ms<br>";
}
```

In the code I just have to put:
if (isset($timetrace)) echo "CPU$==# initiation time = ".ms();

That give me the time spent between my last echo. (isset is actually a variable I configure at the beginning to see if I am in 'time debugging mode')

If I pass 1 - echo "CPU$==# initiation time = ".ms(1); - I get the result of the total duration of the script since the top of the page instead of the last echo.

Here is a sample of the output:

```
CPU$==# INSERT = 12.4 ms
CPU$==# DATE SET FOR GOOGLE QUERY = 530.4 ms
CPU$==# GOOGLE QUERY EXECUTED = 308.8 ms
CPU$==# INSERT 606 ROW = 12290.3 ms
CPU$==# CLOSE LOG WITH SUCCESS = 25.4 ms
Success
```

And yeah, performance is really terrible. The first 530 ms just to prepare the google query is way too high and 12 seconds to insert 600 rows is insane. Something is badly broken somewhere! =) But at least, now I will be able to benchmark my progression.

Thank you!!!